# cannot add 2-factor auth to google account

Tags: gmail, google-account, google

I have a google account, where supposedly I am super admin, but I can't seem to add 2-factor authentication. My phone number and backup email are attached to the account. But I would like to use an OTP from Authy as 2-factor, but it won't let me:

[image]

According to the internet - there should be an option next to change password, but I don't see it :(

Comment: if someone could add the tag "2-factor-auth" that'd be great